# How to print a variable set in my custom module's inc file in node-contenttype.tpl.php

Tags: theming

I am trying to grab all links under `id="ctl00_ctl00_MainPlaceHolder_MainPlaceHolder_TaobaoLink"`.

Here is the function used in my custom module file:

```
function _taobao_add_tovar($url){
  $url = str_replace('&amp;','&',$url);
  $tovar_page = _taobao_get_page('http://rutaobao.com/pages/item_detail.aspx?ItemId='.urldecode($url));

  $linkz = _taobao_get_block($tovar_page, '"ctl00_ctl00_MainPlaceHolder_MainPlaceHolder_TaobaoLink" title="Открыть оригинальную страницу этого товара на taobao.com">');
  preg_match_all('%<a [^>]+href="(?P<url>[^"]+)"[^>*]*>(?P<text>[^< ]+)</a>%si', $tovar_page, $linkz);
}
```

I've set the `$linkz` variable. How can I print it in node-mycontenttype.tpl.php?

Answer (score 2):

To get a variable to a custom node.tpl.php you need to do this in `MODULE_preprocess_node(&$variables)` usually this is done in your template.php file located inside your themes directory, however, because you are calling a private function `_taobao_get_page()`, I think you need it inside your module.

Something like

```
MODULE_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
   if ($node->type == 'mycontenttype') {
      $variables['linkz'] = X;
   }
}
```

Now you can call $linkz inside your tpl.php file

Comment: It throws me an error - Parse error, unexpected '['

Comment: variables['linkz'] = $variables['linkz'].  Edited my answer

Comment: If you are trying this inside your custom module, then let me know if this works and if the $node variable is available.   I know the $node is available in the theme's THEME_preprocess_node() function